# MySQL retrieve value of specific newly inserted column

Tags: mysql, select, insert

I have a SQL that inserts some data into a table and uses some built-in functionality, like MD5.

For example:

```sql
INSERT INTO some_rainbow_table (a, b) VALUES ("Hello", MD5("Hello"))
```

I would like to retrieve the inserted value of `MD5("Hello")` (the md5 hash of "Hello").

Can I realize this in the insert SQL itself, or do I need to query the data again with the `LAST_INSERT_ID`?

Comment: AFAIK MySQL does not support `RETURNING/OUTPUT`, but MariaDB does: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insertreturning/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO some_rainbow_table (a, b) 
       VALUES ("Hello", @md5 := MD5("Hello"));
SELECT @md5;
```